# Help with Linear Algebra Question, Don't Understand Different Notations

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a [Homework Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs72t.png) I'm working on and I really don't recall my Linear Algebra very well. I can't get started on it because I don't understand a lot of the notation.

1. What does the bold capital M mean?
2. Is there any significance to saying that the coordinate system is rotated?
3. What does the prime or apostrophe signify?
4. What does the -1 subscript mean?
5. Any tips for getting started on this?

Answer (score 2):

1. Bold letters are often used to denote matrices. In this case, $\bf{M}$ is the same matrix that appears earlier on that line: $\bf{M}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$. Similarly, $\bf{R}$ in the following line is the $2 \times 2$ matrix with the trig functions. Looks like they forgot to make it bold, but don't let that throw you off. There's no difference here between $R$ and $\mathbf{R}$, it's just an aesthetic typesetting choice.
2. This is a broad question; you might want to ask it separately.
3. Primes typically indicate that a variable is somehow related to the non-prime version; here, $x'$ is like writing $x_\textrm{new}$. The notation is more or less arbitrary; they could have used $\hat{x}$, for example.
4. It denotes the inverse of the matrix.
5. Practise multiplying some matrices; go back to the fundamentals of linear algebra; learn how inverses work. It might be informative to try some simple values to see what's actually happening: if $\bf{M}=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, for example, then plot a few points $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$ as well as their image $\bf{M}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$ and see what $M$ is actually doing. What about $M=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$? And so on.

Good luck!

Comment: You are fantastic, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. The bold capital $M$ represents the matrix.
2. I am confused with this question. What do you mean significant? In reference to what?
3. The prime is way of denoting the image of a transformation (or the new values as a consequence of the transformation).
4. The -1 refers to the inverse matrice.
5. If you have trouble with these symbols, you may want to go back and review linear algebra as a whole. To get started on the notation, you can visit this link: http://linear.ups.edu/html/notation.html

Good luck!